# Execute a double inner join in sqlalchemy

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have this SQL-Query, which I would like to turn into sqlalchemy code.
I'm working here with an already existing database in production which makes it difficult to change.

```
SELECT      B.IDTestung, B.Ber1_Konzentration,
            T.Testungstyp, T.Timestamp,
            K.Name_Kl, K.Vorname_Kl
FROM        BCRS AS B
            INNER JOIN
            ttestungen AS T on B.IDTestung = T.IDTESTUNG
            INNER JOIN
            tklienten K on T.IDKLIENT = K.IDKLIENT
```

So, basically there's the table BCRS, which contains an ID for the "Testung" and the table ttestungen itself has an ID to identify the client. So there are two inner joins to combine three tables.

How do I write this in sqlalchemy?
What I got so far:

```
from auswertungen.data.data import Tklienten, BCR, Ttestungen

tests = session.query(BCR).join(Ttestungen.tklienten).all()
```

This makes the first join, but I don't know how to make the second. I tried to just add another .join(...) after the first one, but that didn't work.

Here's is the DB-Definitions (excerpt):
(automatically created with sqlacodegen)

```
class BCR(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'BCRS'

    IDBCRS_Testung = Column(INTEGER(11), primary_key=True)
    IDTestung = Column(ForeignKey('ttestungen.IDTESTUNG', ondelete='CASCADE'), unique=True)
    [...]

    ttestungen = relationship('Ttestungen')


class Ttestungen(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'ttestungen'

    IDTESTUNG = Column(INTEGER(10), primary_key=True)
    IDKLIENT = Column(ForeignKey('tklienten.IDKLIENT'), index=True)
    [...]

    tklienten = relationship('Tklienten')
```

Comment: Maybe `tests = session.query(BCR).join(Tklienten.IDTESTUNG).join(Ttestungen.IDKLIENT).all()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below:

```
test = session.query(BCR).join(Ttestungen, BCR.IDTestung == Ttestungen.IDTESTUNG).join(Tklienten, Ttestungen.IDKLIENT == Tklienten.IDKLIENT).all()
```

Comment: This runs without error, but I still don't get the client data (the columns from tklienten). Very strange. :-(